# On Lagarias's Equivalent Formulation of the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

A result by Lagarias is that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to:

$$ \sigma(n) \leq H_n + \exp(H_n)\log(H_n)$$

Where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$, and $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$. I was curious if the above inequality is known to hold if we replace $H_n$ with $\log(n)$, or possibly $\log(n) -\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Since $H_n = \log n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + O(n^{-2})$ we certainly do not know that the inequality holds if $H_n$ is replaced with $\log n$. In fact, we know that $\sigma(n) > \log n + n\log \log n$ for infinitely many $n$, since $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log \log n} = e^{\gamma} > 1\,.$$

Comment: I've tried variants of this kind of inequalities in terms of particular values of the Lambert $W$ function. In recent past years this special function was in the literature of prime numbers. This function, that you can to know (I refer for all), from the Wikipedia *Lambert* $W$ *function* has many applications. The idea is try to get a nice expression from some formulation of the Riemann hypothesis that have (we evoke a possible) physical meaning, and after return to the LHS and try to evoke a meaning for the sum of divisors function. I hope don't disturb, are just my beliefs.